# Canonical ensemble Pathria's derivation

Tags: statistical-mechanics

I'm reading Pathria's Statistical Mechanics but I have one question regarding the derivation of the Canonical ensemble.
The derivation is resumed in this question: [Canonical Ensemble and Combinatorics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/640028/canonical-ensemble-and-combinatorics?rq=1)

My question is: the way it's done the sum is always over the energy levels of the system. However, as I understand from other texts the sum should be over every possible configuration or the degeneracy should be added. Is this a derivation only for non-degenerate systems or there is something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it is that the sum is carried over the (micro) *states* rather than over energy levels. The difference is that several micro-states could have the same energy. As you said, if the sum is carried over energy levels, then it is needed to have into account the degeneracy. In other words:

$$ \sum_{r\in states} e^{-\beta E_r}=\sum_{E} g(E)e^{-\beta E} $$

Comment: I thought of that but what feels strange is that if the energy is degenerated, the step of distributing the ensembles in the levels would be different. However,the book says: "let $E_r$ denote the energy eigenvalues of the systems. If $n_r$ denotes the number of systems which, at any time $t$, have energy value $E_r$..."

Comment: I agree that this nomenclature is a bit confusing. In the section 3.4  "* Alternative expressions for the partition function*"  they address the problem of the degenerated spectrum, so in your question, the energy would be non-degenerated. For me, it still seems more elegant to distribute the ensembles over the kets (states). In this way, you don't have to analyze different cases and the degeneracy appears in a natural way.